# Getting error in list comprehension - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Getting an error with this code
(SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

```
score = [a*a in range(1, 100) if (a*a)%2 is 0 and str(a*a)[-1] is '0']
print(score)
```

Result:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but same code working fine when i use it without list comprehension method.

```
score = []
for a in range(1,100):
    if (a*a)%2 is 0 and str(a*a)[-1] is '0':
        score.append(a*a)
print(score)
```

result:

```
[100, 400, 900, 1600, 2500, 3600, 4900, 6400, 8100]
```

Comment: `[a for a in range(1, 100) if (a*a)%2 is 0 and str(a*a)[-1] is '0']`

Comment: @MenglongLi: no it is a filter clause.

Comment: Apart from the missing `for`, it's not the same, you're appending only `a` instead of `a*a` (or `a**2`). Also, if you're doing it for performance concerns, you might don't want to use list comprehension in this case as you're squaring your `a` three times to get to your result - you can square it only once and do the checkups later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `for a`. Also, you should use `==` to test ints and strings for equality because `is` checks object identity:

```
score = [a*a for a in range(1, 100) if (a*a) % 2 == 0 and str(a*a)[-1] == '0']
```

You could also shorten the `== 0` to a `bool` check and generally consider to use `endswith` for more robust suffix checking:

```
score = [a*a for a in range(1, 100) if not (a*a) % 2 and str(a*a).endswith('0')]
```

See the [docs on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: `str.endswith()` is not more robust than using the `-1` index, in fact it's probably slower but more readable

Comment: @Chris_Rands It is more robust as it will not raise an `IndexError` for the empty string.

Comment: Fair, although that could never occur here, I take the point for the generic case

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thinking about it, you would get away with slicing in the general case `s[-len(suf):] == suf` :) but I do think `endswith` is still more readable and fairly optimized, as well.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the *yield* part of the expression:

```
score = [a in range(1, 100) if (a*a)%2 is 0 and str(a*a)[-1] is '0']
```

You want to add `a*a` to the list, so:

```
score = [a*a for a in range(1, 100) if (a*a)%2 is 0 and str(a*a)[-1] is '0']
```

But the code is very inelegantly. You use `is` which is reference equality. Although most interpreters cache characters, and small integers, it is a bit risky to rely on it: the more assumptions that have to be satisfied for a program to work, the more can go wrong.

Furthermore you can detect whether `a*a` will end with `0`, by checking `(a*a)%10 == 0`. Since `10` is a multiple of `2`, we can even drop the first check then. We can check for an integer `i` being zero with `not i` (this is `True` is `i == 0`).

So a more safe and shorter solution is:

```
score = [a*a for a in range(1, 100) if not (a * a) % 10]
```

This then produces then:

```
>>> [a*a for a in range(1, 100) if not (a * a) % 10]
[100, 400, 900, 1600, 2500, 3600, 4900, 6400, 8100]
```